# Download GitLab repository archive using GitLab API and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, gitlab, gitlab-api

I would like to download (not clone) archive from my GitLab repository, but I get this error

> incorrect header check (Zlib._handle.onerror)

This is my function:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');
var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var targz = require('tar.gz');

function downloadFile(source, destination, name) {
    var options = {
        host: url.parse(source).host,
        port: 443,
        path: url.parse(source).pathname
    };

    var file = fs.createWriteStream(destination + path.sep + name);

    https.get(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            file.write(data);
        }).on('end', function() {
            file.end();
            console.log('File ' + name + ' downloaded to ' + destination);

            targz().extract(destination + '/' + name, destination)
                .then(function(){
                    console.log('Job done!');
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log('Something is wrong ', err.stack);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

The file which is download is type of tar.gz. I try to set some headers but unsuccessful. Source param is like: https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/:ID/repository/archive?token=XXYYZZ

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your file is not correctly downloaded by `https` module which result in extraction error from `tar.gz` module.

You can use `request` module coordinated with `tar.gz` with [`createWriteStream`](https://github.com/alanhoff/node-tar.gz#api) to pipe the extraction directly to the destination folder :

```
var request = require('request');
var targz = require('tar.gz');

function downloadFile(source, destination, cb) {
    var read = request.get(source);
    var write = targz().createWriteStream(destination);

    read.pipe(write);

    write.on('finish', function() {
        cb(null);
    });

    write.on('error', function(err) {
        cb(err);
    });
}

var source = "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/:ID/repository/archive?token=XXYYZZ";
var destination = "/home/user/some/dir";

downloadFile(source, destination, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something is wrong ', err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log('Job done!');
    }
});
```

Note that, for the `finish` event to be dispatched you will need version `1.0.2` of `tar.gz` (see [this issue](https://github.com/alanhoff/node-tar.gz/issues/29)) :

```
npm install tar.gz@1.0.2
```

Comment: Yes I think you are right that this file is not downloaded correctly. I try your code with request module but the error remains: Something is wrong Error: incorrect header check. I also use tar.gz version 1.0.2, but it seems that createWriteStream throw this error anyway.

Comment: It's working for me, I tested with a private access token with a url like : `https://your.git.repo/api/v3/projects/XX/repository/archive?private_token=your_token`. My gitlab API verion is v4 but v3 is working too (gitlab 8.17.3). Can you test with a private token ? (though possibly unrelated)

Comment: I use GitLab API v4 and it works just fine. But in version 3 still get the error - don't know why. I will stick to v4 for that :). Thank you for your help.